# C#, form app. Calling a method in a button click

Tags: c#, forms

My code is a program that generates a random number between 1-4 in button1_click, then passes it to GetQuestion and selects a random question based on what the random number was. It should then check the textbox1 for input on what the answer is, and check if it's correct in the GetAnswer function. Problem is, i can't seem to figure out how to pass the questionNum to GetAnswer without passing it as a parameter. If i tried to pass it as a parameter, my button2_click what calls the GetAnswer, wouldn't work since the method call would need a parameter and i don't know how to make it work. Please help!

```
        public struct QuestionAnswer
        {
            public string question;
            public string answer;
        }
        public QuestionAnswer[] answers = new QuestionAnswer[3];

        private int GetQuestion(int questionNum) 
        {
            QuestionAnswer q1;
            q1.question = "What is a salmon?";
            q1.answer = "Fish";

            QuestionAnswer q2;
            q2.question = "How many meters is a kilometer?";
            q2.answer = "1000";

            QuestionAnswer q3;
            q3.question = "How much is 1 + 1?";
            q3.answer = "2";

            answers[0] = q1;
            answers[1] = q2;
            answers[2] = q3;

            label1.Visible = true;

            if (questionNum == 1) 
            {
                label1.Text = q1.question;
            }
            else if (questionNum == 2) 
            {
                label1.Text = q2.question;
            }
            else 
            {
                label1.Text = q3.question;
            }
            return questionNum;    
        }
        private void GetAnswer()
        {
            label2.Visible = true;
            string answer = textBox1.Text;
            
            if (answer == answers[0].answer && questionNum == 1 || answer == answers[1].answer && questionNum == 2 || answer == answers[2].answer && questionNum == 3)
            {
                label2.Text = "Correct!";
            }
            else
            {
                label2.Text = "Wrong!";
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            GetAnswer();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            label2.Visible = false;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int questionNum = rnd.Next(1, 4);
            GetQuestion(questionNum);
        }
}
```

Comment: Just use a global variable.

Comment: Could you suggest something ? I tried using a global variable but it for some reason produced 0 everytime i reached the GetAnswer method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make use of tag property, if you don't want to use global variable

```
    public struct QuestionAnswer
    {
        public string question;
        public string answer;
    }
    private QuestionAnswer[] answers = new QuestionAnswer[3];

    private int GetQuestion(int questionNum)
    {
        QuestionAnswer q1;
        q1.question = "What is a salmon?";
        q1.answer = "Fish";

        QuestionAnswer q2;
        q2.question = "How many meters is a kilometer?";
        q2.answer = "1000";

        QuestionAnswer q3;
        q3.question = "How much is 1 + 1?";
        q3.answer = "2";

        answers[0] = q1;
        answers[1] = q2;
        answers[2] = q3;

        label1.Visible = true;

        if (questionNum == 1)
        {
            label1.Text = q1.question;
        }
        else if (questionNum == 2)
        {
            label1.Text = q2.question;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = q3.question;
        }
        return questionNum;
    }
    private void GetAnswer(int questionNum)
    {
        label2.Visible = true;
        string answer = textBox1.Text;

        if (answer == answers[0].answer && questionNum == 1 || answer == answers[1].answer && questionNum == 2 || answer == answers[2].answer && questionNum == 3)
        {
            label2.Text = "Correct!";
        }
        else
        {
            label2.Text = "Wrong!";
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(button1.Tag != null && int.TryParse(button1.Tag?.ToString(),out int result))
             GetAnswer((int)button1.Tag);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Visible = false;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int questionNum = rnd.Next(1, 4);
        button1.Tag = questionNum;
        GetQuestion(questionNum);
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your time and help, the TryParse is throwing an error, needs 1 argument. I don't yet know enough to spot what would be a proper solution for this?

Comment: sorry! there was mistake earlier, code updated. I don't think parse even required if you are not setting tag property anywhere in your code other than numeric, you could remove  that condition,

Comment: Hmm.. it gives an unhandled exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Right after clicking button2, i think it has something to do with the "GetAnswer((int)button1.Tag);" part since fiddling with the if statement still gives the error. Any idea what causes this ?

Comment: hmm fixed, besides there is a problem in the logic, it is not specifically checking the correct answer vs correct question, now any correct answer given to any question would display "correct"

Comment: Thank you, the edits worked. Much appreciated, have a nice day and be safe out there!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use a field, like you have for `answers` to keep track of your current question.

Now, I've refactored your code to see how you might go about writing this.

```
private Random _rnd = new Random();
private int _questionIndex = 0;

public QuestionAnswer[] _answers = new QuestionAnswer[]
{
    new QuestionAnswer() { Question = "What is a salmon?", Answer = "Fish" },
    new QuestionAnswer() { Question = "How many meters is a kilometer?", Answer = "1000" },
    new QuestionAnswer() { Question = "How much is 1 + 1?", Answer = "2" },
};

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Visible = true;
    string answer = textBox1.Text;
    label2.Text =
        answer == _answers[_questionIndex].Answer
        ? "Correct!"
        : "Wrong!";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Visible = false;
    label1.Visible = true;
    _questionIndex = _rnd.Next(0, _answers.Length);
    label1.Text = _answers[_questionIndex].Question;
}
```

Comment: Oh alright, thanks for your time! I'll study this approach too and figure it out.